# mongo Queries With Multiple Expressions Specifying the Same Operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nodes, node-modules

Hello I am trying to perform the following query in my database

```
function getChat(nameChat, nameUser, callback) {
global.db.collection('chatUsers').find({ 
    $and: [ 
        { $or : [ { nameChat: nameChat }, { nameChat: nameUser } ] },
        { $or : [ { nameUser: nameChat }, { nameUser: nameUser } ] }
    ]
}).sort({date: 1}).toArray(
    function (err, docs) {
        if (err) return console.log("algo deu errado" + err);
        console.log("exit\n"+docs+nameUser);
        callback(docs);
    }
);}
```

But the query returns empty Here is an example of the objects I have in my chat Users collection:

```
{"_id":"5bc3e6d060d4da04dcd66517","nameChat":"Daciolo bolsominion","nameUser":"Mc Xhamps","date":"2018-10-14T17:22:00.000Z","msg":"Você pertence a URSAL"}

{"_id":"5bc52fc3b878631f84c77c41","nameChat":"Mc Xhamps","nameUser":"Daciolo bolsominion","date":"2018-10-01T17:25:00.000Z","msg":"E ai, bora ser Presidente"}
```

To be clear I would like my query to return all objects that name Chat or name User are present in the same object
This query with this is only returning empty objects.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Erik change the and with or you will get required result.

```
global.db.collection('chatUsers').find({ 
    $or: [ 
        { $or : [ { nameChat: nameChat }, { nameChat: nameUser } ] },
        { $or : [ { nameUser: nameChat }, { nameUser: nameUser } ] }
    ]
}).sort({date: 1})
```